# Use async/await for Woocommerce API calls in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, woocommerce, async-await, woocommerce-rest-api

We use some async/await syntax for some fs functions in our call and want to introduce a Woocommerce API call and use async/await but I am struggling with the syntax.

```
  const WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');

  exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) =>{

      const orderFileName ="1141";
      let wooOrderDetails;

      var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
        url: 'http: //example.com',
        consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        wpAPI: true,
        version: 'wc/v1'
    });

      WooCommerce.getAsync('orders/' + orderFileName).then(function(result){
        return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
        wooOrderDetails = JSON.parse;
        console.log(wooOrderDetails);

        let wooOrderID = wooOrderDetails.id;
        let wooOrderNumber = wooOrderDetails.number;
        let Email = wooOrderDetails.billing.email;
    });

    // Update order as Completed
      const status ={
        status: 'completed'
    };

    // Update WooCommerce Order Notes via API
    WooCommerce.post('orders/' + orderFileName, status, function (err, states, res){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Update WooCommerce order with status');
        const data ={ note: 'Status Updated';
      });

        WooCommerce.post('orders/' + orderFileName + '/notes', data, function (err, data, res){
            if (err) throw err;
            else console.log('Woo Order Notes Update:');
      });
    });
    });
  };
```

The [NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api) has some async examples but I cannot get them to work properly. Mainly I think issues with the return process of the function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Woocommerce API functions to async/await using NodeJS in AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627760/change-woocommerce-api-functions-to-async-await-using-nodejs-in-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you transform `xyzAsync(a,b).then(result => {code})` to `result = await xyzAsync(a,b); code;`. So your first `getAsync` (which contains some minor errors, btw) becomes:

```
const result = await WooCommerce.getAsync('orders/' + orderFileName)
const wooOrderDetails = JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
console.log(wooOrderDetails);
let wooOrderID = wooOrderDetails.id;
let wooOrderNumber = wooOrderDetails.number;
let Email = wooOrderDetails.billing.email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible error-fixed and working code in async-await style:

```
exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {

    const orderFileName = "1141";
    let wooOrderDetails;

    const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
        url: 'http: //example.com',
        consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        wpAPI: true,
        version: 'wc/v1'
    });

    const result = await WooCommerce.getAsync('orders/' + orderFileName);
    wooOrderDetails = JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
    console.log(wooOrderDetails);
    let {id: wooOrderID, number:wooOrderNumber, billing} = wooOrderDetails;
    let {email} = billing;

    // Update order as Completed
    const status = {
        status: 'completed'
    };

    // Update WooCommerce Order Notes via API
    try {
        const statusResults = await WooCommerce.post('orders/' + orderFileName, status);
        console.log('Update WooCommerce order with status');
        const data = {note: 'Status Updated'};

        const notesResults = await WooCommerce.post('orders/' + orderFileName + '/notes', data);
        console.log('Woo Order Notes Update:');
    } catch (e) {
        // throw error or take actions you want
    }
};
```