# is there any solution to make asynchronous requests to woocommerce api in python?

Tags: python, woocommerce

is there any solution to make asynchronous requests to woocommerce api in python?

I saw here a solution in javascript >> [Use async/await for Woocommerce API calls in AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092820/use-async-await-for-woocommerce-api-calls-in-aws-lambda) .

is there any module like this in python?

Comment: Have you tried the requests module?

Comment: Requests modul does not support to use async await.

Answer (score 1):

[AioHTTP](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) is one of the most commonly used library for performing asynchronous requests in Python.

Comment: Do u know how to integrate this librate with the woocommerce rest API > https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-a-product ?